# Firebase Wildcard Paths For Security Rules Not Working?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm using the Objective-C API for Firebase to fetch data and am able to do so when my security rules (set via the Firebase online dashboard) don't utilize any wildcard paths, e.g.:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user" : {
      ".read" : true,
      ".write" : true
    },
    "users" : {
      ".read" : true,
      ".write" : false
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try enact what should be identical security rules using wildcard paths and fetch objects, the completion handler never executes, e.g.:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user" : {
      ".read" : true,
      ".write" : true
    },
    "users" : {
      "$userId" : {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used the Firebase documentation at the following URL and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html

I don't think the problem is Objective-C specific, but just to be thorough I'm using the method `-[FQuery observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) { }]` to fetch my data.

---

**Update:** Here's the output of `po query` for the particularly FQuery I'm using to debug:

```
(/users {
    ep = 0;
    i = hidden;
    sp = 0;
})
```

**Update 2:** Here's my data structure, in case that is relevant:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "HhMeloQDY4" : {
      "info" : {
        "name" : "Anita Borg"
      }
    },
    "QxnjCNOj3H" : {
      "info" : {
        "name" : "Charles Babbage"
      }
    },
    "zeNalC4ktf" : {
      "info" : {
        "name" : "Beyoncé"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "HhMeloQDY4" : {
      "hidden" : false
    },
    "QxnjCNOj3H" : {
      "hidden" : false
    },
    "zeNalC4ktf" : {
      "hidden" : true
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 3:** Here's my Objective-C code for how I create my FQuery object:

```
Firebase *firebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<my-app-name>.firebaseio.com"];
[[firebase childByAppendingPath:@".info/connected"] observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    BOOL isConnected = [snapshot.value boolValue];
    // broadcast whether app is connected to Firebase
}];
Firebase *directory = [firebase childByAppendingPath:@"users"];
FQuery *query = [directory queryOrderedByChild:@"hidden"];
query = [query queryEqualToValue:value];
[query observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    // data successfully retrieved from Firebase
}];
```

Comment: What does `FQuery` point to?

Comment: FQuery is a query class from the Firebase Objective-C library: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FQuery.html

Comment: I know what class it is. I want to know what it points to, because that is likely going to point why your read operation fails.

Comment: Not 100% what you're asking but I've added the `po` from the debugger for the FQuery instance I'm using to test.

Answer (score 2):

You have added read access at the path `/users/specific_user_id/` but you're attempting to read at the path `/users/`, which has no read access allowed.

You'll need to provide access to the path you are attempting to read, not just a subset of its children. See [security rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter).

Edit: Just adding some ObjC code to clarify

With the query presented

```
Firebase *directory = [self.myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"users"];
```

you are querying the nodes directly inside the users node. However, if you review the structure, what's inside the users node is not queryable as there are no rules *directly under* /users, where I have commented.

```
"users" : {
  //OH NOES! There are no rules here!
  "$userId" : {
     ".read" : true,
     ".write" : false
   }
```

Your rules are inside the $userId, which represents and applies to that parent only

```
"$userId" : {
    //these rules *only* apply inside each userId.
    ".read" : true,
    ".write" : false
}
```

So with your structure, this query would work and it would query the content inside users/HhMeloQDY4 only.

```
Firebase *directory = [self.myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"users/HhMeloQDY4"];
```

So the end result is that you need to assign the rules directly under the /users node that will allow you to query for content within it's child nodes.

```
"users" : {
  ".read" : true,
  ".write" : false
  "$userId" : {
  }
```

This would allow you to read each node under users node ($userId and it's children) but not write to them.

Comment: I understand that security rules are not filters, but am confused by where I am attempting to read from `/users//` rather than `/users/`, and I think that in both of my security rules I am explicitly allowing read access via `".read" : true`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've added an update to the question that includes my data structure, in case that clarifies anything. I'm still confused as to how my question is a duplicate.

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty Can you update your question with the actual ObjC code (be brief please) you are using to query/observe the node in question. Kato's answer is correct but seeing your code (which may be malformed) may help us get you going in a better direction and help you get the rules straightened out.

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty you're trying to use Firebase security rules to filter data, which is simply not possible. To be able to query `/users` you must have read access to `/users`, which your rules don't allow.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hmm. I would like to provide full read access to `/users` and am explicitly *not* trying to filter using security rules by setting `".read" : true` under `$userId`, but I must be misunderstanding something about how wildcard path rules work.

Comment: @Jay Done! Hope this helps.

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty I added some content to the answer that may clarify it in an ObjC way. The question is kind of a duplicate but if you are just getting started with rules, trying to decipher the info in the question linked can be daunting. However, it was a strong question so once you wrap your brain around the rules a bit, refer back to the other question and answer.